# Determining default qualification thresholds for ntpstat

Tags: ntp, clock, man, ntpdate, ntpd

I have been looking into the `ntpstat` command, more specifically how it determines whether or not the clock is synchronized. From the man page, I see the following excerpt:

```
ntpstat returns 0 if clock is synchronized.  ntpstat returns 1 if clock
is  not  synchronized.   ntpstat returns 2 if clock state is indetermi-
nant, for example if ntpd is not contactable
```

The first line particularly interests me, and leaves me wondering what standards does ntpstat use to qualify a clock as synchronized? For example, in the output of the ntpstat command, I usually find something similar to the following:

```
time correct to within 42 ms.
```

Does ntpstat use a threshold (i.e. must be correct to within 200 ms) to determine this return code?

Comment: Do you understand how NTP works?  Because the protocol sort of explains, "what standards are used to determine if the clock is synchronized", to put it simply the strantum of the source is factored into the calculation which is based on the delay, offset, and jitter of the source.  "Does ntpstat use a threshold (i.e. must be correct to within 200 ms) to determine this return code?" - This is based on the configuration that ntpd is using.

Comment: The answer to your first question would be 'no'. I apologize for any further stupid questions but I have two more. Where can I find the configuration ntpd is using? And can I find this calculation explicitly written out anywhere?

Comment: You shouldn't take down the question.  You should simply improve it.  If you continue to remove questions like this, eventually you won't be able to ask additional questions, once that happens you can't ask more questions.  So do yourself a favor and simply improve this question.

Comment: "Where can I find the configuration ntpd is using?" - Depends on the OS.  "nd can I find this calculation explicitly written out anywhere?" - Of course there is.  The algorithm is described [here](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-algo.htm)